# How to use selenium download multiple files in a loop

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download multiple files using selenium. The script works for downloading one file. But in a loop, after the first download, it can't find any of the page elements anymore.

url: https://www.grants.gov/web/grants/search-grants.html

```
def runExtractor(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url);
        self.driver.maximize_window();

        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)

        self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='embeddedIframe']"))

        df = pd.read_csv ('nofos.csv')
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                self.search(row["oppnum"])
                time.sleep(2)
                searchGrants = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='SearchGrants-tab']/a")));
                searchGrants.click()
            except Exception:
                logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        self.driver.close();
```

The code fails at this line:

```
searchGrants = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='SearchGrants-tab']/a")));
```

This is the error:

> ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\name\Documents\workspace\lab\scraper\extractor.py", line
> 44, in runExtractor
> searchGrants = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
> "//li[@id='SearchGrants-tab']/a")));   File
> "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
> line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

This is is the rest of the code:

```
def search(self, name):
        oppNum = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='oppNum']")));
        oppNum.send_keys(name)

        searchBtn = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='searchBtn']")));
        searchBtn.click()

        archived = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='archived']")));
        archived.click()

        closed = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='closed']")));
        closed.click()

        if (self.check_exists_by_xpath("//div[@id='searchResultsDiv']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a")):
            selectResult = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='searchResultsDiv']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a")));
            selectResult.click()

            time.sleep(10)

            relatedDocumentsTab = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='relatedDocumentsTab']")));
            relatedDocumentsTab.click()

            if (self.check_exists_by_xpath("//div[@id='relatedDocumentsTable']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a")):
                relatedDocument = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='relatedDocumentsTable']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a")));
                relatedDocument.click()
                count = 0
                while not path.exists(self.download + "\\" + name + ".pdf" or self.download + "\\" + name + ".docx" or self.download + "\\" + name + ".doc"):
                    if count > 3:
                        logging.info("File download might be missing for " + name)
                        break
                    time.sleep(5)
                    count += 1
```

How do I return the process back to the page? so I can download the next file by returning to the search page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by calling the return to default content function before clicking the search tab since the search result area was within an Iframe:

changed:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                self.search(row["oppnum"])
                time.sleep(2)
                searchGrants = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='SearchGrants-tab']/a")));
                searchGrants.click()
```

to:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        self.search(row["oppnum"])
        self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
        time.sleep(1)
        searchGrants = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='SearchGrants-tab']/a")));
        searchGrants.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='embeddedIframe']"))
    except Exception:
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```